# Is it okay to bail out early when length mismatch is detected?

Tags: authentication, authenticated-encryption, timing-attack

Is it okay to bail out early when length mismatch is detected?

Specifically, when verifying authenticated encryption, is it okay to bail out early if the wrong amount of ciphertext or the wrong amount of associated data is given?

As I understand it, these two are generally public quantities, and so this does not result in a timing attack.

Comment: What is your threat model against which you want to determine if bailing out early is okay?

Comment: "Is it okay to" reveal "when length mismatch is detected?" ​ ​

Comment: Most AEAD ciphers do not check the length, because there is no recorded length in the ciphertext

Comment: Moreover: how do you know that you have the wrong length?
It sounds like you have some external functionality (packet sizes?) around the outside of your AEAD system that tells you what size the content should be. As Richie says, most AEAD schemes do not require an *explicit* length parameter -- they work it out from the size of their inputs -- so as far as AEAD is concerned there isn't really a concept of 'length mismatch'